# How do I Add to the Value of an Integer when a CheckBox is Checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want value to be added to an integer (int priceTotal), when a Checkbox is checked. The exercise is for ordering a pizza in a webform. I want to be able to add to the price total depending on which size is selected and what toppings.

```
int priceTotal = 0;

if (smallPizzaCheck.Checked) 
{
    priceTotal + 10;
}
else if (mediumPizzaCheck.Checked) 
{
    priceTotal + 13;
}

//Et cetera, et cetera

orderTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(priceTotal);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int priceTotal = 0;

  if (smallPizzaCheck.Checked) 
 {
  priceTotal = priceTotal + 10;
 }

 else if (mediumPizzaCheck.Checked) 
 {
 priceTotal = priceTotal + 13;
 }

 //Et cetera, et cetera

 orderTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(priceTotal);
```

> Just try this....whenever check box checked...the price total
>   added..again and again... so you can sum into (priceTotal value) and 
>   display into textbox name("orderTotal.Text")

Comment: _"Just try this.."_ is not a good answer. Add some text please (like "Your problem is ... but if you ... For example: ...").

Comment: 2 more things: `smallPizzaCheck.Checked == true` is redundant - `smallPizzaCheck.Checked` is enough. `priceTotal = priceTotal + 10` can be shortened to `priceTotal += 10`. Just IMHO.

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from the question, apart from the `==true`s which as mentioned by @vasily.sib is redundant.

Comment: @AnoopRDesai the asker forget to assign result of `priceTotal + 10` to `priceTotal`

Comment: @vasily.sib Ah, my bad, missed it!

Comment: Redundant: `smallPizzaCheck.Checked` will return true not need to check true/false

Answer (score 2):

You are currently adding the values `priceTotal` and e.g. `10`, but not storing the result of that operation:

```
if (smallPizzaCheck.Checked) 
{
    priceTotal + 10; // Will be new sum, but where are your keeping the result?
}
```

You should do this to *update the value of `priceTotal`*:

```
priceTotal = priceTotal + 10;
```

In a simple case like this however, there is a simplified syntax available:

```
priceTotal += 10; // Update priceTotal by adding the value on the right.
```

Note  the `+=`. This essetially means "*add or combine whatever is to the right of the operator with the value to the left of the operator*".

> Sidenote: I say *whatever* in stead of *the number* because this syntax also works for other cases like strings (concatenation) and events (adding subscribers / event listeners), although that is beyond the context of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some more code? You set int priceTotal = 0 before adding. Looks to me it resets the total always to 0 before you add something.
In a real live ordering system you would be able to add more than one pizza.

To to make sure you keep an exising total I would do it like that:

```
int priceTotal;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderTotal.Text))
{
    priceTotal = Convert.ToInt32(orderTotal.Text);
}
else
{
    priceTotal = 0;
}
```

Then you can add to the current total.
Hope this helps.